# Are React Native macOS menu bar apps possible?

Tags: macos, reactjs, react-native, native

Is there any way to currently create a React Native app that runs in the background within the macOS menu bar?

Comment: React Native app for macOS? React Native apps only target iOS and Android mobile platforms.

Comment: There's a library that allows react-native dev on macOS https://github.com/ptmt/react-native-macos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of now, the best way to do this is using the Electron platform.

Comment: "Best". No, actually the best is to write for the platform you want to run using the platform toolkit, not JavaScript.

Comment: @LeoNatan that is not an answer to the question just your personal opinion and adds nothing to the subject whatsoever.

Comment: @RIK Good thing I didn't post it as an _answer_ but as a _comment_ then.

Comment: @LeoNatan Fair dinkum

Comment: There is new a way using Microsoft desktop efforts over React Native, I've created a new answer with further details. Still not officially supported by the platform, but with a simple Swift class it's possible to inject the React Native Root View into a NSPopover and implement the UI over JS "natively".

Answer (score 5):

The question is not recent, but I found it searching for this topic and there is a recent relevant update: with the new desktop efforts from Microsoft, this is now feasible, although still tricky.

Credits to [ospfranco](https://github.com/ospfranco) for the great work.

---

The only way to do it is by editing your `AppDelegate` class and initialize the status button label and its popover content with the Root View content from the React Native application. It's also possible to customize its size, appearance and the button at the bar, but only in Swift code.

```swift
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
    let jsCodeLocation: URL

    jsCodeLocation = RCTBundleURLProvider.sharedSettings().jsBundleURL(forBundleRoot: "index", fallbackResource:nil)
    let rootView = RCTRootView(bundleURL: jsCodeLocation, moduleName: "tempomat", initialProperties: nil, launchOptions: nil)
    let rootViewController = NSViewController()
    rootViewController.view = rootView

    popover = NSPopover()

    popover.contentSize = NSSize(width: 700, height: 800)
    popover.animates = true
    popover.behavior = .transient
    popover.contentViewController = rootViewController

    statusBarItem = NSStatusBar.system.statusItem(withLength: CGFloat(60))

    if let button = self.statusBarItem.button {
        button.action = #selector(togglePopover(_:))
      button.title = "Tempomat"
    }

  }
```

References:

- React Native MacOS (Microsoft): https://github.com/microsoft/react-native-macos
- Sample code: https://github.com/ospfranco/react-native-macos-menubar-template
- Blog post: https://ospfranco.github.io/post/2020/05/23/how-to-make-a-react-native-menu-bar-app-for-mac-os/